# Binding to QListView

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2, qlistview

I'm trying to list the items from a `QStringList` to QML, but I keep getting an undefined error for the bindings.

Here is the C++ code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));  

    QStringList lst;
    QString m("item 1");
    lst.append(m);

    QQmlComponent comp(&engine);
    QQmlContext *ctx = engine.rootContext();
    ctx->setContextProperty("pLst", QVariant::fromValue(lst));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Here is the QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: root; objectName: "root"
    title: qsTr("Doesn't Matter")
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true

    ListView{
        id: lst
        model: pLst
    }
}
```

The error says `pLst` is not defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you call `load()` **before** you set context property, so `pLst` does not yet exists at the moment `ListView` is constructing.

You should call `load()` **after** you set the context properties used for initialization of QML objects.